# Spring RestTemplate post object not not sending in request?

Tags: java, spring, post, resttemplate

I am consuming a web service using RestTemplate and my POST request is as follows.

```
   String url = "http://192.168.1.3:9200/_search";

RestTemplate requestTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            jsonHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

            requestTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonHttpMessageConverter);
    String uuidResult = requestTemplate.postForObject(url, requestBodyJsonObject ,
                    String.class);
```

I tried printing my **requestBodyJsonObject** and put it in a rest client, it works fine so no issue with request body. But here I am not getting the expected result and just getting the result when I send a post request without a request body from rest client.

So I am clueless here. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you maybe look this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570082/spring-resttemplate-post-object-not-not-sending-in-request#new-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call simple like this, dont add

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
```

with rest template
            jsonHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

Sample :

```
RestTemplate requestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Login responseEntity=null;
            try {
                 responseEntity = restTemplate.postForObject("/http:localhost:8080/login", login,
                        Login.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return responseEntity;
```

Comment: So, what is the difference with my implementation?