# Spring RestTemplate POST request is not working with HttpEntity<String>

Tags: java, spring, http-headers, resttemplate

I am not able to call Spring RestTemplate with HttpEntity for POST request.
My call to RestTemplate gives Base64 string in Postman but using my java implementation it gives following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 5b
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My implementation is:

```
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(searchRequestInput, headers);

            final ResponseEntity<String> postForEntity = restTemplate
                    .postForEntity(baseURL, request, String.class);

            String response = postForEntity.getBody();
```

I have tried following solutions, but it didn't work
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570082/spring-resttemplate-post-object-not-not-sending-in-request)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401909/spring-resttemplate-post-response)
 Also I have refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240495/base64-encoding-illegal-base64-character-3c?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpMessageConverter to request your restTemplate call for HttpEntity.
Which can read and write Strings from the HTTP request and response.

From [doc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-android/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/rest-template.html#StringHttpMessageConverter): By default, this converter supports all text media types (text/*), and writes with a Content-Type of text/plain.

You can try this by implementing StringHttpMessageConverter as below:

```
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(searchRequestInput, headers);
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
            messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

then call restTemplate with your request.

Comment: its working. Thanks. HttpMessageConverter  parsed response as it was base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

Try these utility methods:

```
public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> makeRestRequest(Object entity, String restUrl, HttpMethod method, Class<T> entityClass) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity httpEntity = makeHttpEntity(entity);
    ResponseEntity<T> response = null;

    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(restUrl, method, httpEntity, entityClass);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getStatusCode());
    }

    return response;
}

public static <T> HttpEntity makeHttpEntity(T entity) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    HttpEntity<T> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(entity, headers);
    return httpEntity;
}
```

*Where in the these two method*

> - entity: your input object
> - restUrl: your url
> - HttpMethod: POST/GET
> - entityClass: expected output object from the server

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @cpatel please send your input data here

Comment: Hi, It's working by adding this 3 lines. Thanks. final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(searchRequestInput, headers);
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code may it help you:

```
 final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    HttpEntity requestEntity;
    if (entity instanceof String) {
        requestEntity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    } else {
        requestEntity = new HttpEntity(searchRequestInput, headers);
    }
       try {
        String response  =  restTemplate.exchange(baseURL, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class).getBody().toString());
       } catch (HttpServerErrorException | HttpClientErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
```